# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector in wildFly 21.x

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to run a spring boot project which runs perfectly on embedded tomcat but when deployed to wildfly 21.x throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector

Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code snippet.

Main file:-

```
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CdPlaylistadapterApplication {

    @Value("${http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CdPlaylistadapterApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createStandardConnector());
        return tomcat;
    }

    private Connector createStandardConnector() {
        Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
        connector.setPort(httpPort);
        return connector;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml snippet

```
        <cxf.version>3.4.0</cxf.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
             <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
             <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency> 
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Error:-

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.att.dtss.playlistadapter.CdPlaylistadapterApplication] from ClassLoader [ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.cd-playlistadapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:455)
        at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:151)
        ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
        ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector from [Module "deployment.cd-playlistadapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" from Service Module Loader]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:255)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        ... 45 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector` is part of Tomcat. In order for your application to work correctly on external servlet containers, the embedded copy of Tomcat must **not** be on the classpath of the web application (i.e. in `/WEB-INF/lib`). You set it correctly by setting the scope of the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` to `provided`.

However now you have a problem, because the `CdPlaylistadapterApplication` has `Connector` in one of its method signatures and Spring Boot fails while creating an instance of the `CdPlaylistadapterApplication` class.

To solve it you need to move Tomcat specific configuration to another class (even nested) and protect it with the `@ConditionalOnClass` annotation:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CdPlaylistadapterApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

   @Configuration
   @ConditionalOnClass({Servlet.class, Tomcat.class, UpgradeProtocol.class})
   static class EmbeddedConfiguration {

      @Value("${http.port}")
      private int httpPort;

      @Bean
      public ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer() {
         TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
         tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(createStandardConnector());
         return tomcat;
      }

      private Connector createStandardConnector() {
         Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
         connector.setPort(httpPort);
         return connector;
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(CdPlaylistadapterApplication.class, args);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```